# Are multibit HD (or other no web wallet) and Blockchain.info wallet words compatible?

Tags: blockchain.info, multibit, backup, seed, wallet-recovery

Well the title says it. I tried to enter blockchain.info seed words into multibit, but it doesn't seem to be working.

So what I'm trying to do is to have multibit (or other) alternative of my blockchain.info wallet so I can send bitcoins when blockchain.info is down.

Comment: I think you are asking two different questions: 1) How can a Blockchain.info wallet be imported to a desktop wallet? 2) How can I use a wallet in parallel on blockchain.info and a desktop wallet. The two questions don't necessarily have to have the same answer, but your question is loaded because you postulate that they do.

Comment: As far you don't create new addresses it is one question, because I'm asking to send bitcoins and nothing more. The problem is obvious and real, because blockchain.info was down recently several times and this is easy solution how to recover your bitcoins. Of course you need to backup private key every time you add new address. If you do both wallets will show all transactions and correct balance, so you can use them in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The wallet Blockchain.info offers to users is not an deterministic wallet, as such the mnemonic they present is not compatible with any other piece of software other than their own. If you have your wallet.aes.json file downloaded it can be opened with a very old version of MultiBit Classic, other than that you will have to wait for the centralized wallet to be available again before you can send money.

Comment: Thank you for correct answer, however I solved my problem using electrum wallet. I imported the private keys of my blockchain.info wallet, and that worked.

Comment: Good to know. Just keep in mind that you will not be able to recover this custom wallet setup using the seed, so keep your wallet file safe.